# Where is the certificate file for SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations in OpenSSL located on a Mac?

Tags: c, openssl

I see `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` like for example, [here](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-openssl/):

```
if(! SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "/path/to/TrustStore.pem", NULL))
{
    / Handle failed load here /
}
```

Also [here](https://gist.github.com/appcoreopc/c8b5121e114828636fd2d46816e1efc8#file-openssl_client-c-L61):

```
/* verify truststore, check cert */
if (!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,
                                    "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt", /* truststore */
                                    "/etc/ssl/certs/")) /* more truststore */
```

Also in this nice [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=IIqwAy4qEl0C&pg=PT127&lpg=PT127&dq=openssl+c+api+programming+in+depth&source=bl&ots=mc643U7BYx&sig=ACfU3U3EPNqUldTaMio-eM3UWBnDty9eqw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi84rm04oLmAhXQs54KHUmZC0w4ChDoATACegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=openssl%20c%20api%20programming%20in%20depth&f=false). They say it is located in `/usr/local/lib` or somewhere around there (for UNIX), but I don't see it anywhere on my Mac. For me, OpenSSL was here `/usr/local/opt/openssl`, but none of the subdirs had any certs.

Where do I find these certs? How do I get them gathered so I can plug them into that function?

I also see a seemingly related one, `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file`, like [here](https://github.com/darrenjs/openssl_examples/blob/master/common.h#L316), but maybe that is just for "server" situations, not "client":

```
/* Load certificate and private key files, and check consistency */
if (certfile && keyfile) {
  if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, certfile,  SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) != 1)
    int_error("SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file failed");
```

Comment: I *think* you're asking where the system-wide trusted root certificate store is located on a Mac ? I don't know, but was just looking for clarification.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: That's a helluvagood question, I've never seen access to it outside of the system crypto API and System KeyChain. Bump.

Comment: I am not sure if it is still valid, but https://hynek.me/articles/apple-openssl-verification-surprises/ suggests that Apple's shipped version of OpenSSL patches in an extra certificate verifier which checks the Keychain certs for you and (apparently?) can't be disabled. AFAIK, there *is* no authoritative trust store on macOS outside of the keychain.